# Switch case with Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I'm having problems to set a Switch Case with the value of a Select options, here's the code I'm using:

```
<form id="selectcub" name="selectcub">
    <select id="cub01" name="cub01" class="cub">
        <option value="2013" selected>2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
    </select>
                   
    <select id="cub02" name="cub02" class="cub">
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03" selected>03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
                    
    <a id="cubdl" href="#" class="button">Open</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        switch($('#cub02 option:selected').val()) {
            case 01:
                alert("I am an alert box! 1");
            break;
            case 02:
                alert("I am an alert box! 2");
            break;
            default:
                //
        }
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is a live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/whC97/

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to `$(document).ready()`, and not on the click of your link. So the javascript is checking the value on load, and the value is `03` for which you don't have any `case`.

If you change the default selected on `01` and put the cases in quotes you can see it works alright.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, as it's technically correct, at page load the selected option does have "03" as a value, and the switch only works on pageload.

Comment: Really nice, thank you so much, and sorry for the delayed response, I'm too busy lately =/
Put the cases in quotes and made the function "$("#cub02").change(function(){" instead of "$(document).ready()".
Thank you so much and sorry for the silly question.

Comment: There is no such thing as a silly question. Perhaps you would like to use a [**self executing anonymous function**](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) as well

Answer (score 6):

`val()` is always going to return a string. Try putting "01", "02", etc. in your `switch` statement.

Comment: *or* `parseInt($('#cub02 option:selected').val(), 10)` (but even then the leading-zero would be stripped off, so  using strings is easier).

Comment: +1 Not only will `val` return a string, but `switch` compares cases (in order) using `===`, so there's no type coercion.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:
One: as said before, val() is returning a string, so you have to use for example '01'.
Two: The function is called right when the dom is ready, so there will only be an alert if you look for '03' as that is selected in your code.
You are probably looking for an event listener...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cub02').on('change', function(){
        switch($('#cub02 option:selected').val()) {
            case '01':
                alert("I am an alert box! 1");
            break;
            case '02':
                alert("I am an alert box! 2");
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

And the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/whC97/11/

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/whC97/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    switch (parseInt($('#cub02').val())) {
        case 1:
            console.log("I am an alert box! 1");
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log("I am an alert box! 2");
            break;
        default:

    }
});
```

Comment: You should set the base because here number start with 0: parseInt($('#cub02').val(),10)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the string representation, You should use parseInt(val) or switch the case statement to use the quoted string version of your numbers

http://jsfiddle.net/whC97/9/

Modifying Example Provided:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    var val = $('#cub02').val();
                    switch(parseInt(val)) {
                    case 01:
                        alert("I am an alert box! 1");
                    break;
                    case 02:
                        alert("I am an alert box! 2");
                    break;
                    default:
                    //
                }
            });
```